# Alternative to exiting environment while messagebox is open

Tags: c#

Example:
Once I display a messagebox, I'd like to call into a function to automatically exit the environment AFTER 5 seconds of the messagebox being displayed.

Is there a better approach towards doing so other than using a timer (starting the timer before the messagebox is displayed)?

Thanks

Comment: what is your idea of a 'better' solution, rather than using a timer to perform an event after an elapsed amount of time?

Comment: @Jonesopolis I feel timers are a bad approach in programming.. Although I'm not too familiar with async tasks, would that be an option/better way?

Comment: If you mean you don't want to use a `Timer` object, you still have to have some construct that counts 5 seconds, then does an action.  Timers are not inherently bad, it sounds like exactly what you need in this scenario.

Comment: Okay, I know this seems like a dumb question but I had to ask and see if I could learn a better approach. Timers just make me think of the terrible setTimeouts in JS.. not very ideal but a work around for certain things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a timer is definitely a valid solution in this case, but you can also leverage `Task`s and `async/await` in order to gain more control over the execution flow. Here's a `Task`-based implementation which calls `Environment.Exit(0)` after the predefined time interval, or immediately after the user dismisses the message box:

```
static void ShowMessageBoxAndExit(string text, TimeSpan exitAfter)
{
    using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        Func<Task> exitTaskFactory = async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(exitAfter, cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                // Expected if the user dismisses the
                // message box before the wait is completed.
            }
            finally
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        };

        // Start the task.
        Task exitTask = exitTaskFactory();

        MessageBox.Show(text);

        // Cancel the wait if the user dismisses the
        // message box before our delay time elapses.
        cts.Cancel();

        // We don't want the user to be able to perform any more UI work,
        // so we'll deliberately block the current thread until our exitTask
        // completes. This also propagates task exceptions (if any).
        exitTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```